# Laravel 7 Login Ajax

Tags: laravel, ajax

Estoy tratando de adpatar un modal de login con ajax y el controlador. Pero me esta dando fallos, esto es lo que tengo:

Cabe mencionar que al poner el email y password correctos e incorrectos aun asi hace el efecto del shakemodal() pero ya de alli no pasa.

Modal Login:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="loginForm">
  @csrf
  <input id="Login-email" class="form-control" type="text"
      placeholder="Correo electrónico" name="Login-email">
  <input id="Login-password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña"
      name="Login-password">
  <input class="btn btn-default btn-login" type="button" value="Iniciar sesión"
      id="loginBtn">
</form>
```

Este es un archivo **login-register.js** que esta en la carpeta public/js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loginBtn").click(function (e) {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        var email = $("input[name='login-email']").val();
        var password = $("input[name='login-password']").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'login',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                email: email,
                password: password
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if ($.isEmptyObject(data.error)) {

                    console.log(data.success)

                } else {
                    shakeModal();
                    printErrorMsg(data.error);
                }
            }
        });

        shakeModal();

    });  
});
```

La ruta definida en web.php

```
Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);
```

El **LoginController** que se encuentra en la carpeta app\Http\Controllers\Auth\

```
protected function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->passes()) {
            if (auth()->attempt(array('email' => $request->input('email'),
                'password' => $request->input('password')), true)) {
                return response()->json('success');
            }

            return response()->json([
                'error' => [
                    'email' => 'Los datos son incorrectos.',
                ],
            ]);

        }

        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
```

Comment: Prueba con `if ( $.isEmptyObject(data.data.error) )`

Comment: tampoco, sigue sin responder y me sigue diciendo usuario y contraseña invalido (aunque si son las correctas)